# How can I use my logo slider JavaScript function inside an Angular component / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Since I'm very new to Angular I need your help. I've watched a lot of tutorials and tried out a lot of stuff but this time I need to merge a JavaScript function into my Angular component.

This is the actual slider I want to use inside Angular (A big thanks to SomoKRoceS):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onload = createAnimation;

  function createAnimation(){

  let e = document.getElementById("logo-gallery"); // Get the element

  var style = document.createElement('style'); // Create styling element
  style.type = 'text/css'; // Append a css type

  // Now create the dynamic keyFrames (that are depend on logo-gallery final width)
  // Notice that the width of e is given to translateX at 100%
  let keyframes = '\
  @keyframes scroll-left {\
      0% {\
          transform: translateX(0);\
      }\
      100% {\
          transform: translateX(-'+e.scrollWidth+'px);\
      }\
  }';
  style.innerHTML = keyframes; // Set innerHTML of the styling element to the keyframe
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style); // append the element to the head of the document as a stylesheet
  e.setAttribute("style","animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite; animation-iteration-count: infinite;"); // Give the element its animation properties.

}
```

```css
#logo-gallery-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#logo-gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

#logo-gallery .logo-gallery-figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1.6rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo-gallery .logo-gallery-figure img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: all .4s;
}

#logo-gallery .logo-gallery-figure img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-gallery-wrapper">
  <ul id="logo-gallery">
    <li>
      <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
        <img src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
        <img src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
        <img src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
        <img src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
        <img src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
        <img src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
        <img src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Actually I've my component with a **.css**, **.html** and **.ts** file. The content of the HTML and CSS file belongs to the content here but now I somehow need to transform the JavaScript to Angular. This is my **.ts** file:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector   : 'app-logo-gallery',
  templateUrl: './logo-gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls  : ['./logo-gallery.component.css']
})
export class LogoGalleryComponent {

  @Input()
  logos: string[];

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I know that there is an animations command available in the @Component decorator but is this the right way and if yes, how can I use it there? The point is that I need to get the scrollWidth somehow calculated and set to the keyframe, otherwise the animation would be faulty.

I already know that I can get the width of an element this way:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="logo-gallery" #logoGallery>
```

**TypeScript class**

```
@ViewChild('logoGallery', {static: false}) logoGallery: ElementRef;

this.logoGallery.nativeElement.offsetWidth
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another aproach is use the Angular Animations. The only thing you need take account is use `@ViewChildren` to get the "htmlElement". I don't like write severals  if I can use a *ngFor, so I use an array and write one li and another using the array. Some like

Some like

```
<div #wrapper id="logo-gallery-wrapper">
    <ul #banner id="logo-gallery"  >
    <li #logo>
            <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
                <img (load)="resize()" src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let i of items;let first=first">
            <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
                <img  src="https://www.ikea.com/de/de/static/ikea-logo.f88b07ceb5a8c356b7a0fdcc9a563d63.svg">
      </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See that the first "image" has an event "load", this event is who let me calculate how many element need and start the animation.

```
  logoWidth: number = 0;
  items: number[] = [0];
  public player: AnimationPlayer;

  @ViewChild("wrapper") wrapper: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("logo") logo: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("banner") banner: ElementRef;

  constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder) {}


  resize() {
    this.logoWidth = this.logo.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.createAnimation();
  }

  createAnimation() {
    if (this.wrapper && this.logo) {
     //width of the "wrapper"
      const totalWidth = this.wrapper.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
        .width;
      //number of element I go to paint
      const element = 2 * Math.floor(totalWidth / this.logoWidth);

      //I go to translate the "half" of the "ul"
      const inc = this.logoWidth * (element / 2);

      //I recalculate the number of elements if you resize the window
      if (this.items.length != element)
        this.items = new Array(element > 0 ? element : 1);

      // the time spend in the animation is proportional to the "total width"
      const time = 9.2 * totalWidth + "ms";

      //create a manual animation
      const myAnimation: AnimationFactory = this.builder.build([
        style({ transform: `translateX(0px)` }),
        animate(time, style({ transform: `translateX(${-inc}px)` }))
      ]);
      this.player = myAnimation.create(this.banner.nativeElement);

      //when finish repeat process
      this.player.onDone(() => {
        this.createAnimation();
      });

      //finally lauch the animation
      this.player.play();
    }
  }
```

you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-izszv3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) be careful! if you change the code you need refresh the .html to step the animations before -else you can crash your navigator-

And additional advantage is that you can pause/start the animation using mouseover and mouseout

```
<ul (mouseover)="player.pause()" 
    (mouseout)="player.play()" 
   #banner id="logo-gallery"  >
...
</ul>
```

**Update** what happens if we want to have a series of imgs and noy only one?

The technica it's the same, we need repear the series of the images to cover the total width. Imagine we has an array "repeat". We need makes two loops. Our array with the images are called "logos"

```
<div #wrapper id="logo-gallery-wrapper">
    <ul (mouseover)="player.pause()" (mouseout)="player.play()" #banner id="logo-gallery">
        <li #logo>
            <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
                <img (load)="resize()" [src]="logos[0].url">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let i of repeat;let firstRepeat=first">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let logo of logos;let firstLogo=first">
                <li *ngIf="!firstLogo || !firstRepeat">
                    <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
                        <img  [src]="logo.url">
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Again take account that we first write the first image, and then makes the two loops. This is neceary because is this first image in the event "load" who desencadetate the animation. And it's not possible added in the loop because we are going to change "repeat array", and this will makes that we create a new animation each time this resize.

Well, it's some complex the twoo loop because we need not paint this image

Again, we has a function createAnimations

```
createAnimation() {
    if (this.wrapper && this.logo) {

      //calculate the total width
      const totalWidth = this.wrapper.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
        .width;

      //number of copies necesary
      let copies =
        2 * Math.floor(totalWidth / (this.logos.length * this.logoWidth)) + 1;
      //at least must be 2
      if (copies == 1) copies = 2;

      //create an array with somany elements than "copies"
      this.repeat = ".".repeat(copies).split("");

      //we are going to move lo the left only the width of the "first group of images"
      const inc = this.logoWidth * this.logos.length;

      //rest of code similar, but the speed is proportional to inc
      const time = 9.2 * inc+ "ms";
      const myAnimation: AnimationFactory = this.builder.build([
        style({ transform: `translateX(0px)` }),
        animate(time, style({ transform: `translateX(${-inc}px)` }))
      ]);
      this.player = myAnimation.create(this.banner.nativeElement);
      this.player.onDone(() => {
        this.createAnimation();
      });
      this.player.play();
    }
  }
```

(*)To check if all goes good, we can change the .css style to `overflow:scroll` and coments this lines to be sure we are calculate good the "copies" and the "inc"

As usually, a [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-co1onr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the changes

**Update** and... what's about the logos has different width?

Well, in this case we are going to change the .html. We makes a loop with the logos and another one with repeat

```
<div #wrapper id="logo-gallery-wrapper">
    <ul (mouseover)="player.pause()" (mouseout)="player.play()" #banner id="logo-gallery">
        <li *ngFor="let logo of logos" #logo>
            <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
                <img (load)="loaded()" [src]="logo.url">
      </figure>
        </li>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let i of repeat">
                <li *ngFor="let logo of logos">
                    <figure class="logo-gallery-figure">
                        <img  [src]="logo.url">
          </figure>
                </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See that in this case the `(load)` event call to a function loaded. The idea is that in this function increment a variable -picsLoaded- when all the logos are loaded we calculate the total width. See that we need use ViewChildren, not ViewChild

```
  totalLogoWidth: number = 0;
  picsLoaded=0;
  @ViewChildren("logo") logo: QueryList<ElementRef>;

 loaded()
  {
    this.picsLoaded++;
    if (this.picsLoaded==this.logos.length)
    {
      let totalWidth=0;
      this.logo.forEach(x=>{
        totalWidth+=x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      })
      this.totalLogoWidth=totalWidth
      this.createAnimation()
    }
  }
```

Now, just updated the function createAnimation to use totalLogoWidth instead this.logos.length*this.logoWidth

```
  createAnimation() {
    if (this.wrapper && this.logo) {
      const totalWidth = this.wrapper.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
        .width;
      //in this case "copies" is simply Math.floor +1
      let copies =Math.floor(totalWidth / (this.totalLogoWidth)) + 1;
      this.repeat = ".".repeat(copies).split("");
      const inc = this.totalLogoWidth;
      const time = 9.2 * inc + "ms";
      const myAnimation: AnimationFactory = this.builder.build([
        style({ transform: `translateX(0px)` }),
        animate(time, style({ transform: `translateX(${-inc}px)` }))
      ]);
      this.player = myAnimation.create(this.banner.nativeElement);
      this.player.onDone(() => {
        this.createAnimation();
      });
      this.player.play();
    }
  }
```

Another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f8zcqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

you can put js function in a component. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-javascript-example-y6nw2t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

function createAnimation() {
  let e = document.getElementById("logo-gallery");
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.type = "text/css";
  let keyframes =
    "@keyframes scroll-left { 0% {transform: translateX(0);}100% {transform: translateX(-" +
    e.scrollWidth +
    "px); }}";
  style.innerHTML = keyframes;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
  e.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite; animation-iteration-count: infinite;"
  );
}
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  ngOnInit() {
    createAnimation();
  }
}
```

But I generally dont choose to use function as a way I choose put one css inside component css [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-javascript-example-ws1bm6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
@keyframes scroll-left 
{
   0% {transform: translateX(0)}
  100% {transform: translateX(var(--m,100%))}
}
```

and give animation to css

```
#logo-gallery {
  animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

and with Viwchild

```
 @ViewChild('logoGallery', {static: false}) logoGallery: ElementRef;
    
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        let element=this.logoGallery.nativeElement;  
        element.style.setProperty('--m',element.scrollWidth+"px");
      }
```

Comment: But is this the correct (nice) way? Just to be sure I learn everything right :)

Comment: I edited answer with second way that I choose to use rather than js function

Comment: Works well but it runs in the wrong direction somehow :D Should be from right to left. Any idea?

Comment: In demo it works right to left . Did u put minus as prefix in set property ? @Mr.Jo and Viewchild starts to work first in AfterViewInit

Comment: Yes my fault - you're right! But one question, is it possible to let the logos completely going to the left and jumping then back to beginning? Because this way the user has no time to watch the last logo you know

Comment: It is much more about css and I am not good at css too much. You can ask this in stack overflow with css tag as a new question. Then  you can get answer @Mr.Jo